# Block port on all interfaces using PF

Tags: firewall

Trying to block incoming traffic on all interfaces to a specific local port on Mac OS X 10.11.15, including loopback.

This is my /etc/pf.conf:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"

block in quick to any port 63342
```

However, when attempting to apply this rule, I get an error (line 29 is the one with the block rule):

```
✗ sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
/etc/pf.conf:29: port only applies to tcp/udp
/etc/pf.conf:29: skipping rule due to errors
/etc/pf.conf:29: rule expands to no valid combination
pfctl: Syntax error in config file: pf rules not loaded
```

What would be the correct syntax in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper rule is:

```
block in quick inet proto { tcp, udp } from any to any port 63342
```

Some parts may be omitted (e.g. *inet* or *from any*) with a slightly different meaning.